# How to pause audio tag when screen off or start second one

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to pause audio when mobile screen off or run a second audio tag.
this is sample example of my html code

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="audio1.mp3">
  Does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src="audio2.mp3">
  Does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Unfortunately I don't know how can I make EventListener to check the above cases.

Comment: _when mobile screen off_ - When someone turns their phone off?

Comment: Yes, because when the screen black the sound doesn't stop